# Exceptions of different types return status codes

Tags: php, exception

I am having a problem catching Exceptions , all i need is to convert the error code given by this exception and converting it to a status code but i can't seem to understand the logic behind it or the right way to do it.

I have done an array error_codes, in which i have a key which is the error code and the status code as value.

CustomException Class:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {

    private static $ERROR_CODES;
    
    public function __construct($message,$code = 0, Throwable $previous = null) {
        if (!isset(self::$ERROR_CODES)) self::$ERROR_CODES = (require __DIR__.'/../../config/error_codes.php')();
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
    
    public function getStatusCode() {
        $status_code = (array_key_exists($this->getCode(),self::$ERROR_CODES)) ? self::$ERROR_CODES[$this->getCode()] : self::$ERROR_CODES['default'];
        return $status_code;
    }


}
```

code scope (in which you only need to check the catch part)
in this code: JWT can throw Exceptions , the User model can also throw database related exceptions

```
 try {
            //tocheck if isset, because if username is not available it will throw an error;
            $auth_header = $request->getHeaderLine('Authorization');
            $USER_DATA = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);

            if (!empty($auth_header)) throw new CustomException('User already Logged in',40013);
            if (!is_string($USER_DATA['username']) || empty(trim($USER_DATA['username'])) ||
                !is_string($USER_DATA['password_hash']) || empty(trim($USER_DATA['password_hash'])))
                throw(new CustomException('', 40001));

            $user = User::login_user($USER_DATA);

            /******* JWT ******/
            $jwt_secret_key = $this->settings['jwt']['secret_key'];
            $jwt_algorithm = $this->settings['jwt']['algorithm'];
            $payload = array(
                'sub' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'username' => $user->username,
                'exp' => time() + 3600
            );    
            $token = JWT::encode($payload, $jwt_secret_key, $jwt_algorithm);
            $response->getBody()->write($token);
            $response = $response->withHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);
            $response = $response->withStatus(200);
            // $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($decoded));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof PDOException) return $response = $response->withStatus($this->getStatusCode($e->getCode()));
            $e = ($e instanceof CustomException) ? $e : new CustomException($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());
            $response = $this->print_error($e,$response);
            $response = $response->withStatus( $e->getStatusCode());
        }

        return $response;
```

okay so the problem is , i dont think its a good practice but i can keep on creating new CustomExceptions ,but if the Exception thrown is of type PDOException or SQLException, in which the code '42S22' which is a string i get an error when using ->getCode() , i don't understand how when i read the documentation getCode() returns an int but in this case its a string, and its causing an error.
if someone could explain to me a good approach to handle all the errors and return only the status code related to them i would be more than grateful

thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i get an error indicating that i am trying to construct Exception with an error code of type string, in this line of code ``` parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
``` the $code provided by PDOException for example is '42S22' which is a string

Comment: You can convert the code to int without much trouble. See my answer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a case for the CustomError class to be anything more than the static map and the `getStatusCode()` function which could easily take the exception's error code as an argument and become static.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the code into int this way:

```
parent::__construct($message, intval($code), $previous);
```

The reason of the error that you received was that the constructor of the parent class (see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php)) is explicitly declared to receive an int code.

EDIT

If you have a String that cannot be converted properly to int, such as 42S22, then you will need to either accept that the result of intval with such an input is 0, or to convert it to another numeric value that's more appropriate for you.